# Find column value contained in another column R

Tags: r, string-concatenation

I have multiple columns of addresses, where they may contain duplicated information (but generally will not have exactly duplicated information).

The following code will provide an example of my issue,

```
id= c(1, 2)
add1 = c("21ST AVE", "5TH ST")
add2 = c("21ST AVE BLAH ST", "EAST BLAH BLVD")
df = data.frame(id, add1, add2) 
df$combined = paste(add1, add2)
df
```

This gives the following result,

```
  id      add1             add2                  combined
1   1 21ST AVE 21ST AVE BLAH ST 21ST AVE 21ST AVE BLAH ST
2   2   5TH ST   EAST BLAH BLVD     5TH ST EAST BLAH BLVD
```

The conclusion I need is the following,

```
  id      add1             add2                  combined
1   1 21ST AVE 21ST AVE BLAH ST          21ST AVE BLAH ST
2   2   5TH ST   EAST BLAH BLVD     5TH ST EAST BLAH BLVD
```

I wish to identify if what's in `add1` is contained in `add2`. If I find that `add2` contains the same information that `add1` provides, then I either want to avoid combining those particular column values or delete the repeated information in the combined column (which I believe would require solving a different issue of repeated phrases in a string). I have not been able to find an example of finding column values that are 'contained in' rather than 'exact' - and I'm working with over 500K cases in a dataset where this issue is a common occurrence. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We `split` the second and third column by one or more space (`\\s+`), then `paste` the `union` of the corresponding rows with `mapply` to create the 'combined'

```
lst <- lapply(df[2:3], function(x) strsplit(as.character(x), "\\s+"))
df$combined <- mapply(function(x,y) paste(union(x, y), collapse=" "), lst$add1, lst$add2)
df$combined
#[1] "21ST AVE BLAH ST"      "5TH ST EAST BLAH BLVD"
```

---

Or another option is `gsub`

```
gsub("((\\w+\\s*){2,})\\1", "\\1", do.call(paste, df[2:3]))
#[1] "21ST AVE BLAH ST"      "5TH ST EAST BLAH BLVD"
```

Comment: This is perfect, I hadn't thought of using a union - but that's basically what I was looking for. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to accomplish this where the `ifelse` tests whether`add1` is in `add2`, and if so, then doesn't include it, otherwise it combines them:

```
id= c(1, 2)
add1 = c("21ST AVE", "5TH ST")
add2 = c("21ST AVE BLAH ST", "EAST BLAH BLVD")
df = data.frame(id, add1, add2, stringsAsFactors = F) 

require(stringr)
require(dplyr)

df %>% mutate(combined = ifelse(str_detect(add2, add1), 
                                add2, 
                                str_c(add1, add2)))
```

Output:

```
  id     add1             add2             combined
1  1 21ST AVE 21ST AVE BLAH ST     21ST AVE BLAH ST
2  2   5TH ST   EAST BLAH BLVD 5TH STEAST BLAH BLVD
```